# Fields, Buttons, Custom Links and Mobile & lighting Actions are not visible on User page layout for edit

Tags: page-layout, user, fields, button, custom-link

I am trying to create a section but the field itself is missing in page layout. Please see image below. Missing required options on the left side to edit the page. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much context from your question, I’m guessing you will need to update the user profile page layout, not the user page layout.